# PopOver bootstrap with fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover

I create calendar view with fullcalendar.io. And now at every event I have button so when I clickI show some data from event at popover.

And this looks like this:

```
function startPop(){
    $('.btn').popover({
    template: '<div id="myPopover1" class="popover popover-default">'
    +'<div class="arrow"></div>'
    +'<div class="popover-title"><span class="close" data-dismiss="popover-x">&times;</span>Title</div>'
    +'<div class="popover-content">'
    +'<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p></div>'
    +'<div class="popover-footer">'
       + ' <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button><button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Reset</button>'
    +'</div>',

});
};


function popForBook(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.btn').not(this).popover('hide');
    var j = $(this).attr('price');
    $('.popover-content').text(j);
});
};
```

but now when I change month popover window stay at changed month , also I can't click on new events on changed month, so I cant view details of event at popover window...

I try to solve this with:

```
$('.fc-left, .fc-right').click(function() {
    startPop();
    popForBook();
    });
```

but dont work...
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Also I try to find event onMonthChange at fullcalendar docs but that option does not excist... So I'm in problem now.